# DatePicker Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I have to set the startdate/Mindate in jquery datapicked calender. i am using datepicker v1.7.2. and using mindate and max date prpperty but its not working fine.

Comment: Mind to explain what is not working? and while you're at it, try adding some codes here.

Comment: can you post your code here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. In this the end date is 1 day after start date.

```
$('#enddate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd M yy",
    beforeShow: customRange,
    //Your other configurations.
    });

  function customRange(input) {
   if (input.id == "enddate")
    {
    dateMin = new Date();
    if ($("#startdate").datepicker("getDate") != null)
    {
    dateMin = $("#startdate").datepicker("getDate");
    dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() + 1); //here we are adding 1 day to start date/
    }
    }
    return {
    minDate: dateMin
  }; 
}​
```

Comment: Please, see the below...problem